# Perl match blank lines with m/^ *$/

Tags: regex, perl

This is the perl script:

```
while ($line = <>)
{
        if ($line =~ m/^ *$/)
        {
                $line = "--blank\n";
        }
        print($line);
}
```

That replaces all blank lines in file with `--blank\n`.

I don't get why it is working. Why does this regex `m/^ *$/` matches blank lines ? Because there is newline character at the end of line it must not match.

UPDATE:

I assume: `^` is the beginning of line, `*` is no or as many spaces as possible, `$` end of line.

Empty line must be something like this: `[ ][ ][ ]\n` that is `^` then `[ ]*` then `\n` and `$`.

Why do they match ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: `^`: Start of line, ` *` means any number of spaces, `$`: End of Line.

Comment: `$` doesn't match any character as far as I know, that doesn't include `\n`. Or does it ?

Comment: you are correct; `$` is always a zero-width match; it does not match a `\n`.  But it can match before one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$` matches at either the end of a string or before a newline at the end of a string.

Comment: Thanks that clarified things. Everywhere they say it's just "end of line" and I got the wrong idea.

Comment: @nikachx, Be careful of what documentation you read. There are many regex engine, and they all have their differences. For example, `$` is indeed the end of <strike>line</strike>string in some other engines. In Perl, that's `\z`. In Perl, `$` is equivalent to `(?=\n\z|\z)` (without the `m` modifier) or `(?=\n|\z)` (with the `m` modifier).

Comment: @ikegami I am reading `Advanced Regular Expressions` of O`Relly. It is't really a reference I just came up with this expression that worked unexpectedly.